# Prevent PDF file from saving in a browser

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I want to show some information on my site in a PDF file. But I don't want user to download or save that PDF file on his system. Can we avoid the PDF from saving?

Comment: No, it's not possible. If you make a PDF available to a browser, then (depending on what reader software they have installed) the user can often just click on a save toolbar button, and take a copy. Adobe writer software does make it possible to prevent copying to clipboard, and printing, but I should think even these protections can easily be removed.

Comment: You could convert the PDF to a high-res image and display that instead. However this creates a trade-off between the security of your information and its accessibility, which is worth considering.